# Converting a docker-compose redis file to work on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, redis, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I'm migrating our swarm cluster to a k8s one, and that means I need to rewrite all the composes files to k8s files. Everything was going smothy, till I reach the redis compose...

The compose file from redis:
Yes, Its simple because is just to test during development for cache stuff...

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    deploy:
      labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:our-redis-url.com
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.so==linux
    networks:
      - traefik
networks:
  traefik:
    external: true
```

So, we have 4 nodes in that swarm... my DNS (our-redis-url.com) is pointing to one of them, and it works like a charm. I simple connect to redis using that url + the port 6380.

Now.... I have created the same thing, but for k8s, as follow:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-ms
  namespace: prod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-ms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-ms
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis-ms
        image: redis:alpine
        ports:
          - containerPort: 6379
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 512Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-ms
  namespace: prod
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis-ms
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 6380
    targetPort: 6379
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: redis-ms
  namespace: prod
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: our-redis-url.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: redis-ms
            port:
              number: 6380
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

And that didn't work.
The pod run, and by the logs I can see it's waiting for connections, BUT I don't know how to do the trick like in docker-compose (traefik.frontend.rule=Host:redis-ms.mstech.com.br to bind the url and the port part).

I have tried to use the tool kompose to convert this compose file... It didn't work to lol

If anyone could bring me some advice, or help me fix the problem I'll thankfull.

I'm using k8s with traefik as ingress controler.

Comment: The Redis service isn't HTTP, so the Kubernetes Ingress system by default doesn't know how to deal with it.  [Exposing Redis with Ingress Nginx Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939846/exposing-redis-with-ingress-nginx-controller) has a pretty detailed walkthrough, but for the Nginx ingress controller, not Træfik.  Do you actually want your private data store accessibly from outside the cluster at all, though?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, the Ingress system is only for HTTP traffic. Traefik does also support TCP and UDP traffic but that's separate from Ingress stuff and had to be configured through Traefik's more-specific tools (either their custom resources or a config file). More commonly you would use a LoadBalancer-type Service which creates a TCP LB in your cloud provider.

Comment: I'll try the aproach by David Maze, searching for Traefik stuff like Nginx. Thx for the tips!